# npm ERR! while installing next.js

Tags: node.js, npm, eslint, next.js

I have a problem like while I am trying to install next.js using `npm install --save next` then showing below error like

> npm ERR! Unexpected end of JSON input while parsing near '...:{"eslint":"3.19.0","'

I just stack into that for past several hours.
How can I resolve that?

```
package.json

{
  "name": "a-client-project",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "node server.js -p $PORT",
    "build": "next build",
    "start": "NODE_ENV=production node server.js -p $PORT"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "body-parser": "^1.19.0",
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "react": "^16.9.0",
    "react-dom": "^16.9.0"
  }
}
```

Info:

```
OS: Windows 10
NodeJS: 10.16.3
NPM: 6.11.3
```

Thanks

Comment: Can you show us your package.json as I believe it to be incorrectly formatted.

Comment: can you post the content of your `package.json` file?

Comment: @TudorConstantin Updated the post with `package.json` file

Comment: @MichaelMano Updated the post

Comment: @jesica i can not replicate this at all, try running `npm cache clean --force` and then give it another go

Comment: looks good to me

Comment: @MichaelMano Yes! it was the trick. Thanks so much :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue was due to the node cache.

`npm cache clean --force`

fixed the issue.

Writing answer here in case anyone else runs across this. :)